# @JsonView not rendering for Spring Boot app deployed in Spark

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, apache-spark

I have a  Spring Boot application, that  has a  Java REST controller  getting data from a Scala class, and  returns a JSON view using `@JsonView` annotation. The code runs fine, and renders JSON when the spring boot app is running on its own, however, when i submit this jar to Spark, i can see the results printed in the REST controller logs, but an empty JSON is rendered on the webpage as `[ { }, { }, { } ]`

Has anyone tried rendring JSON view from springboot deployed in Spark?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get the JSON out by using the following.
Annotated the class members with **`@BeanProperty`**
,then used **`ObjectMapper`** manually as below, and the JSON rendered ok. Would be great if i could still get this done by annotation, to keep the code clean.

new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(myListobj)